# How to set environment variable with heroku?

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to set an environment variable with this command line:

```
heroku config:set ENV=PRODUCTION
```

But I have this error :

> !    Missing required flag:
>
> !    -a, --app APP  app to run command against
>
> !    See more help with --help

my app name is disquairedjangoaj96

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need now is to tell heroku in which app you want to set the env variable.

`heroku config:set ENV=PRODUCTION --app disquairedjangoaj96`

Maybe this guide can help you https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-the-cli#app-commands

Comment: when I do so, I get this error:  "!    disquairedjangoaj96 is invalid. Must be in the format FOO=bar."

Comment: Did you used the double "--"?... I received that same error when I used only "-app" instead of "--app"